# Organizar el ID de un conjunto de elementos añadidos dinámicamente al eliminar uno de ellos con Jquery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

necesito su ayuda, tengo la siguiente funcion que esta asociada a un boton que tiene `onclick="addPageNew()"` esta funcion crea elementos con su respectivo ID dinámicamente uno abajo del otro con Jquery, `codigo`:

```
function addPageNew(){

let idPageNew = generarID();

//aqui cuento la cantidad de elementos en el dom que tienen la clase '.page-edit' para poder crear un id consecutivo.

let contador = $('.page-edit').length + 1;

//template
let newPageHTML = `

<div class="page-edit-full mb-4" id="${idPageNew}">

    <div class="row mx-auto mb-2 mt-4 align-items-center page-tools-menu">

        <div class="col">

            <div class="page-number-label d-inline">Página ${contador} - </div>
            <p class="mb-0 d-inline page-titulo-label" contenteditable="true">Agregar título</p>

        </div>

        <div class="col text-right">

            <a href="#!" onclick="deletePage('${idPageNew}');" class="btn-delete-page"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>

        </div>

    </div>  

    <div data-page-num="${contador}" class="page-edit p-5" id="page${contador}">

    </div>

</div>

`; 


contentPageMain.append(newPageHTML);


}
```

Y elimino esos elementos con la siguiente funcion:

```
function deletePage(idDeletePage){

let deletePage = $('#'+idDeletePage);


$(deletePage).animate({ 
    opacity: 0,
  }, 'fast', 'linear', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });

  }
```

> El problema es el siguiente:

Si agrego 3 elementos dinamicamente entonces pasaria esto:

> elemento 1 `con id: page1` y nombre `pagina 1`
>
> elemento 2 `con id: page2` y nombre `pagina 2`
>
> elemento 3 `con id: page3` y nombre `pagina 3`

**Todo bien hasta ahi.**

*Pero:*

Si elimino el segundo elemento con id: `page2`

entonces la secuencia de paginas quedaria de la siguiente manera:

> elemento 1 `con id: page1` y nombre `pagina 1`
>
> elemento 3 `con id: page3` y nombre `pagina 3`

**Conclusion:**

Como podria hacer yo para que cada que vez se elimine un elemento, la enumacion de id se vuelva a poner en un orden ascendente? 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5, etc.

Ojala me puedan ayudar! gracias.

> Lo de arriba ya lo pude resolver gracias a Alvaro!

**EDIT:**

resulta que yo guardo el contenido de cada pagina, y yo lo hacia con esta funcion:

```
function autoGuardado(){

   var countPagesAutoguardado = $('.page-edit').length;

   var contentPagesArrayAutoguardado = [];
   var objeto = {};

   for(var i = 1; i <= countPagesAutoguardado; i++) {

       contentPagesArrayAutoguardado.push({ 
          "pagina" : $('#page'+i).html()
       });

   }
   objeto.datos = contentPagesArrayAutoguardado;

   let dataInformeAutoguardado = new FormData($("#formInforme")[0]);
   dataInformeAutoguardado.append("numPages", countPagesAutoguardado); 
   dataInformeAutoguardado.append("contentPagesArray", JSON.stringify(objeto));

}
```

> Como se pueden dar cuenta, guardo el contenido de cada pagina, mediante un `for(){}` y recorro cada pagina con su id mas el iterador, osea: `page1, page2, page3`

**El problema ahora es:**

> Si yo tengo 3 elementos:

elemento 1 con id: page1 y nombre pagina 1

elemento 2 con id: page2 y nombre pagina 2

elemento 3 con id: page3 y nombre pagina 3

Y elimino el 2, entonces ya no existiria la pagina con el id, page1.
por lo que el contador solo va a encontrar 2 elementos con la clase .page-edit y el contenido de la pagina 3 se va a quedar excluido, por que la pagina 3 pasaria a ser la 2, alguna recomendacion?

Comment: No deberías usar el ID para esto. Los IDs no deberían usarse para darle un significado particular a un elemento (como se indica en el [estándar HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes)). En su lugar deberías plantearte clases o data atributos, incluso podrías hacerlo con [contadores CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) si lo que quieres es cambiar algún texto dentro de cada uno de ellos.

Comment: Para borrar/editar, en lugar de usar el id, borrarías/editarías el ancestro que contiene al botón pulsado (en jQuery puedes usar `closest()`).

Comment: Alvaro, me pudiste dar una nueva idea, sin embargo aun quedo en las nubes, tus respuesta fueron muy generalizadas. gracias.

Comment: Te estaba escribiendo una respuesta más extensa. En los comentarios no cabe nada ;)

Comment: Oh muchas gracias, ya intente lo del contador con css y funciono muy bien, creo que voy a optar por el.

Comment: Sin embargo, los elementos con los id: page1, page2, page3 - los utilizo para añadir elementos dinámicos dentro de esas paginas, entonces en el for siempre agrego $('#page'+i).append(templateHTML); la variable 'i' seria el contador de esas paginas, entonces como haria para añadir elementos en el orden de las paginas si ya quitaria los id consecutivos?

Comment: Eso sería un tema algo diferente. Pero de nuevo, eso no está relacionado con el contador en sí sino con la página a la que quieres añadir esos elementos. Puedes añadirlos basándote en el botón que se pulsó o usar un ID generado aleatoriamente que no tenga que ver con el orden de la página.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92003/discussion-between-jesus-armanado-araujo-orozco-and-alvaro-montoro).

Comment: Ya pude resolver todas mis dudas, gracias, ya no es necesario contestar.

Comment: Hola, perdón por el retraso. Estaba en la oficina y no podía contestar (me había puesto a contestar durante la comida). Me alegra que encontraras la solución, publícala como respuesta (con el código final que utilizaste) por si a otro usuario le sirve de ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te ponía en los comentarios, los IDs no deben usarse para dar sentido a un elemento, deberían ser cadenas "opacas" como se especifica en el [estándar HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes) (enlace en inglés). En tu caso estás intentado usar el ID para dar sentido a un elemento, especificando su orden.

Una alternativa a esto sería usar los [contadores CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) para especificar el número de página. Para ello resetearías el contador al principio y por cada página (con la clase `.page-edit-full`) incrementas el contador y lo usas en el `::before` o `::after` para mostrar el valor.

Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo funcionando:

> Nota: he creado mi propia función que genera IDs "aleatorios" y he borrado las referencias a los contadores.

```js
function generarID() {
  return "id" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
}

function deletePage(idDeletePage) {
  let deletePage = $('#' + idDeletePage);

  $(deletePage).animate({
    opacity: 0,
  }, 'fast', 'linear', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });

}

function addPageNew() {

  let idPageNew = generarID();

  //aqui cuento la cantidad de elementos en el dom que tienen la clase '.page-edit' para poder crear un id consecutivo.

  const contentPageMain = $("#contentPageMain");

  //template
  let newPageHTML = `

<div class="page-edit-full mb-4" id="${idPageNew}">

    <div class="row mx-auto mb-2 mt-4 align-items-center page-tools-menu">

        <div class="col">

            <div class="page-number-label d-inline">Página</div>
            <p class="mb-0 d-inline page-titulo-label" contenteditable="true">Agregar título</p>

        </div>

        <div class="col text-right">

            <a href="#!" onclick="deletePage('${idPageNew}');" class="btn-delete-page"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>Borrar</a>

        </div>

    </div>  

    <div data-page-num="" class="page-edit p-5" id="page">

    </div>

</div>

`;

  contentPageMain.append(newPageHTML);
}
```

```css
body {
  counter-reset: pagina; 
}

.page-edit-full {
  counter-increment: pagina;
}

.page-number-label::after {
  content: counter(pagina);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button onclick="addPageNew()">Add New Page</button>

<div id="contentPageMain"></div>
```

Comment: Alvaro muchisimas gracias! pero tengo una duda, puedo editar el documento para que me hagas el favor de contestarmela?

Comment: Alvaro ya edite la pregunta, dame una recomendacion porfa.